# Do my maths homework!

Tags: code-golf

*For all you American folk out there, remove the "s" in "maths".*

Ugh, my maths teacher gave me so much algebra to do. There's just lines and lines of meaningless junk like `Expand (x+1)(x+6)` and `Factorise x^2+2x+1`.

My hands are literally dying from the inside.

So I figured out a way to hack the system - why not write a program in my book (and tell the teacher to run it)? It's genius!

Your task is to either expand or factorise the function listed. My hand's already dying, so I need to write as small a program as possible to save my fingers.

## Input:

- The input is either `Expand {insert algebra here}` or `Factorise {insert algebra here}`.
- When the first word is `Expand`, you must expand the algebraic terms. You are guaranteed there won't be more than 5 terms.

  - In the example shown in the intro, the output is `x^2+7x+6`.
  - Some more inputs:

    - `Expand (x+1)(x-1)` = `x^2-1`
    - `Expand x(x-1)(x+1)` = `x^3-x` (notice the `x` on its own - your program must work for that.)
    - `Expand (x+1)^2` = `x^2+2x+1` (notice the `^2` on the outside of `x+1` - your program must work for that.)
- When the first word is `Factorise`, you must factorise the algebraic term.

  - In the example shown in the intro, the output is `(x+1)^2`.
  - Some more inputs:

    - `Factorise x^2+3x+2` = `(x+1)(x+2)`
    - `Factorise x^2+x` = `x(x+1)` (if `x` alone is one of the factors, you must leave it outside the brackets.)
    - `Factorise x^3+9x^2+26x+24` = `(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)` (there are more than 2 terms here - you are guaranteed that the maximum amount of terms is 5.)
    - `Factorise x^2+2x+1` = `(x+1)^2` (if there are multiple repeating terms, group them together - so no `(x+1)(x+1)`, but `(x+1)^2`.

## Specs:

- The pronumeral will always be `x`.
- The terms in the `Expand` bit always contain whole numbers from 1 to 20.
- You are guaranteed that the algebra bit in the `Factorise` part will always be factorised into 5 or less terms, and all the numbers in each term will be whole, and from 1 to 20.
- You are not allowed to use any built-in functions.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program in bytes wins.

*Just as a side-note: it would be appreciated if a pretty-printed output (i.e. With nice-looking exponents)  - I'm looking at you, Mathematica - was included in an answer. You don't have to do it.*

Comment: Just use [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com/) to help you. I think you can use the exact same syntax.

Comment: @LeakyNun Well, not anymore... no builtins. Also, is there anything that's vague or unclear about this challenge?

Comment: Half of this is a dupe of [Factor a polynomial](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38513/194). The other half is close enough to count as a dupe of [Multiply polynomials](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80030/194) (it just wraps a loop). So there's not really anything new here, unless it's supposed to handle non-polynomials too (which isn't actually clear).